# How to update Firebase with struct

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a struct `EventDate` and am trying to update a reference in Firebase.

```
struct EventDate {

    var club: String = ""
    var date: String = ""
    var eventText: String = ""
    var free: String = ""
    var monthYear: String = ""
}
```

My update function throws `lldb`. I guess because the `keys` are no Strings(?)

```
func updateEvent(_ backendlessUserObjectID: String, event: EventDate) {

    let reference = firebase.child("eventDates").child(backendlessUserObjectID).child(event.date)
    reference.setValue(event) { (error, ref) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    } // lldb here
}
```

If I change the function to the following, everything is fine (because `Keys` and `Values` are now Strings?)

```
func updateEvent(_ backendlessUserObjectID: String, event: EventDate) {

    let item: NSMutableDictionary = ["club" : event.club,
                                     "date" : event.date,
                                     "eventText" : event.eventText,
                                     "free" : event.free,
                                     "monthYear" : event.monthYear]

    let reference = firebase.child("eventDates").child(backendlessUserObjectID).child(event.date)
    reference.setValue(item) { (error, ref) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Am I right that I receive `lldb` because the `keys` from my models are not Strings? Or what am I missing and how will I be able to save the values into my Firebase using my model without creating the `NSMutableDictionary`? Help is very appreciated.

PS: `print(event.date)` = `201610120200000000` -> the desired value for `.child`

Comment: Are you sure its `event.date` that you are using in your second code block?

Comment: You mean in `.child`? Yes. Because it's a known String from `yyyyMMddhhmmssSSSS`

Comment: Or what do you mean? I also have printed it and it's the desired value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it has nothing to do with the type of keys that you are trying to save in your Firebase Database its just that `struct` ***is a dataModel or to be precise a physically grouped list of variables*** which you initialise with some custom Data, and you can only save four types of values types in your Firebase Database:-

- ***NSDictionary***
- ***NSArray***
- ***NSNumber***
- ***NSString***

Look up the docs :- [Read And Write data, Firebase- iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

So when you cast your values in a *NSMutableDictionary*, you come clean of struct. And struct and class is not recognisable by the *Firebase Database*.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase data exists in a JSON format which can be thought of as key:value pairs. The keys must be strings and the values can be any of the for data types mentioned in Dravidians answer (which is a correct answer and should be accepted). I would like to add some additional comments that may help as well.

There are times when you want to use a structure in code and that can't be written to Firebase directly - you need some way to get the data out of the structure into something Firebase likes - which is a Dictionary.

Heres an example (Swift 3, Firebase 2.x)

```
struct EventDate {
     var club: String = ""
     var date: String = ""
     var eventText: String = ""
     var free: String = ""
     var monthYear: String = ""

     func getDict() -> [String:String] {
          let dict = ["club": self.club,
                      "date": self.date,
                      "eventText": self.eventText,
                      "free": self.free,
                      "monthYear": self.monthYear
                      ]

           return dict
     }
}


 var event = EventDate()
 event.club = "Wimbledon"
 event.date = "20161023"
 event.eventText = "Special Tennis Event"
 event.free = "Free"
 event.monthYear = "10/2016"

 let ref = self.myRootRef.child(byAppendingPath: "events")!
 let eventRef = ref.childByAutoId() //Firebase 2.x

 eventRef?.setValue( event.getDict() )
```

This results in a node being written to Firebase that looks like this

```
"events" : {
    "-KUli8oiM_KKw8GZ0MMm" : {
      "club" : "Wimbeldon",
      "date" : "20161023",
      "eventText" : "Special Tennis Event",
      "free" : "Free",
      "monthYear" : "10/2016"
    }
 }
```

Comment: this is a pretty awesome answer. 1) you explained it to me 2) you provided a code example to help me 3) you eased the decision of whos answer to accept. upvote for you and i hope you'll receive further upvotes. thank you